# Pandas not adding time when converting string to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string to date using pandas, but can't figure out how to also get time (00:00:00) added.

I have a column named "Date" with the following string formatting: YYYY-MM-DD

python code:

```
import pandas as pd
datetime = pd.to_datetime(data_frame[DATE])
```

Printing `datetime` or exporting it as csv shows only the date, without time:

```
0       2021-09-01
1       2021-09-01
2       2021-09-01
3       2021-09-01
4       2021-09-01
```

However, the expected result `YYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` shows up if I only print one value at a time:

```
print(datetime[0])
```

Outputs: `2021-09-01 00:00:00`

Comment: Use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert as a string of your choice: `data_frame[DATE].dt.strftime(…)`

Comment: Please initialize `data_frame` in your example. Just something trivial and small. We should be able to copy and run your program and it can be the basis for tested solutions.

Comment: if your point is to export to csv, then in the method `to_csv`, there is a parameter `date_format` that probably if you define it like `date_format='%Y-%m-%d %h:%M:%s'`, then in your csv the time will be there

Comment: @Ben.T I have tried that way and the time is not added

Comment: @Valip sure if you want

Comment: @Valip Ben.T's solution does work. If it doesn't it's either a problem with you not making changes to the dataframe, or opening the file in some program that is formatting the display. But the underlying text data will be written with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert as a string of your choice:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

output:

```
                  DATE
0  2021-09-01 00:00:00
1  2021-09-01 00:00:00
2  2021-09-01 00:00:00
3  2021-09-01 00:00:00
4  2021-09-01 00:00:00
```